# Second order Diff. Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve $u''-e^t\cdot u'-e^t\cdot u=1$.

Can somebody put me in the right direction?

Thanx in advance!

Comment: What is t? a constant? or u is a function of t?

Comment: hint: work out the derivative of $e^{t}u$ and go from there.

Comment: If $u$ is not a function of $t$, the problem would be simple. But is it the case ?

Comment: u is a function of t. So working out what Paul suggests: $[e^t\cdot u(t)]'=e^t\cdot u'+e^t \cdot u$ What's next??

Comment: Now integrate both sides of the equation.

Answer (score 0):

We are trying to solve
$$u'' - e^{t}u' - e^{t}u = 1.$$

As Paul pointed out in a comment, we notice that $[e^{t}u]' = e^{t}u' + e^{t}u$, i.e. 
$$u'' -[e^{t}u]' = 1.$$

Now integrate both sides of the equation:

$$\int u'' dt - \int [e^{t}u]' dt = \int 1 dt,$$

$$u' - e^{t}u = t + C.$$

This is a linear, first-order differential equation which is "easy" to solve.

We do so below by introducing an integrating factor (and then discover that we need to solve an integral which doesn't have a simple representation).

$$u' e^{-e^{t}} - e^{t} e^{-e^{t}} = (t+C) e^{-e^{t}}  $$
$$[ue^{-e^{t}}]' =  (t+C) e^{-e^{t}} $$
$$u = e^{e^{t}} \int (t+C) e^{-e^{t}} dt $$

Unfortunately I don't think we can proceed any further - the best we can do is an integral representation for $u$.

Comment: Thanks I believe this is the right direction. Though I can use some help with the 'easy' first-order diff. eq. Say that for the homogeneous soloution: $\frac{du}{dt}=e^t\cdot u$. This results in $u=c_1\cdot e^e^t$. Is this correct? Further on, suppose that $c_1$ depends on $t$. => $u(t)=c_1(t)\cdot e^e^t$. Working out $\frac{du}{dt}=e^t\cdot u+t+C$ gives $\int dc_1(t)=\int \frac{t+C}{e^e^t}dt$. How to solve this integral?

Comment: Yeah, I filled in the details. It looks like that integral doesn't have a solution in terms of elementary functions. This is (I think) the best we can do.